# Postgresql@14/macM1 - Could not bind ipv6 address. Is another service running on port 5432?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, postgresql-14

TL;DR

Creating a DB (Postgresql service) was not working locally since i deployed on Heroku and added a "DATABASE_URL" environment variable in my .env file.
removing this variable did the trick, i could "rails db:create" again after that.

EDIT:
I encountered this problem after deploying on staging on Heroku.
I had a DATABASE_URL variable in my .env that was cascading into all those errors.

This DATABASE_URL is linked to Heroku and my staging env. Just removed this variable from my .env. It somehow infered with the process of authentication of my local user to connect to my postgresql service.
I've been struggling this afternoon with postgresql suddenly not working anymore. I had not been trying to use a local db since deploying a staging env.

I spend the day figuring it out, and after browsing the solutions online, which are mostly about deleting a postmaster.pid file that i don't have or simply restarting the service, i'm still stuck.

When trying to launch manually (without using brew) the postgresql service, i get
(I'm on MAC M1)
[image: trying to launch the service without brew]

I think this error is the closest to the root cause, and to give more context here are some commands that can give hints :
[image: the infamous error]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I find as well this interesting (duplication?):
[image]

And about the fact that my user is root, when i ls -l /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14      or ls -l /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14/posgresql, i still get -rw-------   1 etiennededianous  admin      3 Sep  5 14:36 PG_VERSION, for all the lines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Ps:
I don't get why my user is root. I

I tried everything mentionned above, and fear messing up my config ( i'm still junior )
Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? if not, wait a few seconds and retry.
i checked :
[image]

It seems that I need to try to restart my computer, which i'll do just after posting this and edit if successful.

Comment: So after restarting it worked?

Comment: No. But i finally managed to fix it so i'll edit my original post to add the solution.